# iPhone dial pad/pin code screen for my app REJECTED by Dev - need advice

Tags: ios, iphone

Phone App: Magic Trick
Spectator dials number - on a fake dialpad within the app
(similar to "Santa Claus" apps already in existence in the AppStore)
*Note: My app has been submitted, but rejected:
"8.3 Details Your app contains features that mimic the native iOS pin code screen. We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference"

Q: What are the guidelines? How CLOSE can I come to the real iOS inteface? The closer I can get this app to looking like the real iOS dialpad (it doesn't make a real phone call) the happier my client will be.

Add'l info: the app works fine. It does what it is supposed to do. No coding issues. It just needs to look like the real dialing pad for my client to pay me.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should ask the App Review Board these questions - they're often helpful at clarifying the rules for you.

Comment: I assumed since they didn't help me at all by explaining why it wasn't allowed, it was up to me to figure it out. Which is why I am here asking the question...

Comment: I dont think apple will allow us to mimic the UI that are there in apple devices. Please check the link for reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/